# How would I change a folder to user read and write permissions?

Tags: permissions, chmod

My Nginx folder (etc/nginx and usr/nginx) won't let me do certain things. How would I give both those folders user read and write permissions (with chmod?)? (sorry if this is similar to other questions, although those couldn't help me)

To add some context I want to be able to curl things to the directory and to access the directory via cyberduck ssh.

Comment: Please add some context, like what is your goal? Are you attempting to  write logs (via 1 app), or is this folder for users modify (via SSH login)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each file has three sets of permissions: user, group and others. The user and group are the user and group which the file belongs to (changeable by chown) and others is everyone else.

The permissions that you can set are read/write/execute. So to give all other users the ability to read/write to a folder you would use:

```
chmod o+rw <folder_name>
```

However you probably don't have write permissions for the folder so you need to run this command with root privileges:

```
sudo chmod o+rw <folder_name>
```

And if you want to do the same for all files in the folder then you can do

```
sudo cdmod o+rw <folder_name>/*
```